# Blackberry Toolbar 7.0

Tags: java, blackberry, toolbar

I am trying to create a Toolbar using the `ToolbarManager`.

Now it works fine with the example code, on a screen.

But as soon as I override  `protected void paint(Graphics g){}`

With nothing inside it. It seizes to draw anything.

I need the overriding of paint, so that I can draw my maps. But I also NEED a toolbar.

How do I get it to still render?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call the super constructor first and then do your painting.

so use the following

```
protected void paint(Graphics g)
{
    super.paint(g);
    //do your drawing here
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Considering only 4 ppl viewed the question, your answer is much appreciated!